# youtube video link

Tags: php

I want to create a php application to download my films from youtube.
For example:

page with video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dT312CDPJI
link to video:

```
<a href="http://o-o.preferred.tpnet-waw2.v24.lscache1.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams=id%2Cexpire%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass&fexp=904535%2C902314%2C910701&itag=22&ip=109.0.0.0&signature=A3C9407B96FF5D7548AFBCECFF248B90496CCDF7.5383C61DE0FFD40EEFA9090CB73C616ABF0E3C20&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&expire=1315674000&key=yt1&ipbits=8&id=e5d4f7d760833c92&title=Lykke+Li+-+Little+Bit+%28AutoErotique+Bootleg+Remix%29">video link</a>
```

But I can't find video link in page html. Where is the video link?
Is it possible to do it in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a script you can use for this

http://www.ngcoders.com/php/php-youtube-video-downloader-script

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if it is possible to extract direct video URL and download it using only PHP.

But, I think I have 2 possible path for you:

1. Read and translate [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/) code into PHP
2. Using [Youtube API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html) as mentioned by [@Jleagle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472084/jleagle).

[From this docs](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries.html), you can extract detailed info using url:

```
    https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/5dT312CDPJI?v=2
```

There, you'll see a RTSP url. [You need to process those stream using mencoder](http://stream-recorder.com/forum/archive/record-rtsp-3gp-streaming-videos-youtube-mobile-t1488.html).